# Golang, race condition with local map

Tags: go, race-condition, goroutine

I don't seem to totally understand maps in Go.

I have this code:

```
fetch := map[string]int{some data}

for condition {
    fetchlocal := map[string]int{}

    for key, value := range fetch {
        if condition {
            fetchlocal[key] = value
        }
    }

    go threadfunc (fetchlocal)
}
```

Now wherever the threadfunc function uses the fetchlocal variable Go (go -race) says warning: data race. I also got a few panics already. But why? The fetchlocal variable isn't used by any other goroutine.

Can someone enlighten me, please?

Comment: On each iteration of `for condition {` you spawn new goroutine to process `fetchlocal`, thus if your `threadlocal` works long enough you inner `range` loop may / will change your `map`. `map` is not threadsafe data structure in Go. Also, it will help us to answer if you provide `threadfunc` source too.

Comment: as far as I understand, unless `threadfunc` changes `fetch`, there should be no race, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The threadfunc is 2,000 lines, might be too long to post here. But it just reads from and writes to the fetchlocal variable. But, I thought fetchlocal only exists in that one loop section, since it's created in it. Anyway, someone posted an answer to wrap the go call into a function (but unfortunately deleted the answer). But it seems to have fixed the problem. Also, threadfunc only works (reads/writes) with fetchlocal, leaving fetch alone.

Comment: Is the value of fetch really integer? If it's a mutable object then changing it will cause a race condition. BTW running a slightly modified but basically similar version of your code doesn't trigger race warnings.

Comment: It's not changing it. And in your code, are you sure the go-called function lasts longer than the for iteration?

Comment: @shshsh here is my code - it just proves that the fetchlocal instance being passed to the function changes for each call. http://play.golang.org/p/ykg6Xawpgo

Comment: Please post a minimal example for which a race is reported where each loop iteration processes only loop-local data.

Comment: @shshsh What is `some data` above? If it is data which might be modified by `theadfunc` then there will be a race. See http://play.golang.org/p/FWEz-OEfkq

Comment: This might be a bug in the race detector. Consider filing a bug at http://code.google.com/p/go/issues

Comment: There is a race between reading in threadfunc and writing in "fetchlocal[key] = value"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your `fetch := map[string]int{some data}` was actually supposed to be: `fetch := map[string][]int{..some data..}`.

For this to be a race `threadfunc` must be changing a value within `fetchlocal` or something else must be changing the value within `fetch`.

This is to say a slice is a actually:

```
type SliceHeader struct {
        Data uintptr
        Len  int
        Cap  int
}
```

When you are copying the elements from one map to another you **are not** doing a deep copy of the slices (you are just creating a new struct with the same Data,Len,Cap), that is so say `fetch["foo"].Data == fetchlocal["foo"].Data`.

Therefore you can say `fetch[someExistingKey] = someNewValue` and this will not race with `threadfunc`, but if you say `fetch[someExistingKey][x] == foobar` or `fetchlocal[someExistingKey][x] == foobar` the race will be on.

If `fetchlocal` needs to mutated by `threadfunc` you could change your inner loop to look like:

```
for key, value := range fetch {
    if condition {
        newVal := make([]int, len(value))
        copy(newVal, val)
        fetchlocal[key] = newVal
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, do the copy inside `threadfunc` as needed before mutating.

P.S. If you shared your actual `threadfunc` or code that is modifying `fetch` while these two loops are running, we will be able to help more.